# HTML5 Video - Codec sniffing using canPlayType

Tags: android, html, mobile, html5-video, video-encoding

I am a mobile web javascript developer and we are finding that some Androids will not play our  mp4 container h.264 encoded videos, and so we had logic pointing to 3gp versions.  Now newer Android devices (Samsung Ace, Kindle Fire) do not support the 3GP container.

I am now looking into using the javascript DOM method of canPlayType(), I am having trouble determining the strings that go in there.  I pull the examples from the HTML5 W3C spec and other sources.

With the following code (taken from another question) I get mixed results because I believe I am testing a string that may not match our handbrake/qt-faststart/ffmpeg produced files.

I get a false on all 3 on a Samsung Vibrant, yet it plays all the videos fine.

```
    var testEl = document.createElement( "video" ),
        mpeg4, h264, webm;
    if ( testEl.canPlayType ) {
        // Check for MPEG-4 support
        var typeStr = testEl.canPlayType( "video/mp4; codecs=\"mp4v.20.8\"" );
        mpeg4 = typeStr !== "";

        // Check for h264 support
        typeStr = testEl.canPlayType( "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E\"" )
            || testEl.canPlayType( "video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2\"" )
        h264 = typeStr !== "";
        // Check for Webm support
        typeStr = testEl.canPlayType( "video/webm; codecs=\"vp8, vorbis\"" );
        webm = typeStr !== "";
    }
    alert("mpeg4 = "+mpeg4+"\nh264 = "+h264+"\nwebm = "+webm);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't just add both versions in separate source elements and just let the browser work it out for itself?

Comment: the short answer is I am not actually playing the video through the HTML5 tag because the major mobile platforms play all video through a native video app.  Only the iPad will play through the HTML5 tag inside browser, Android has a poor fragmented implementation and iOS 4+ has a decent implementation of the webkits and html5 specs, but still plays through mobile quicktime. So I need to know how to get the proper strings associated with html5 spec.

Comment: canPlayType( "video/webm" ) returns "" in Android 3.2 and below, then "maybe" in 4+ (including Chrome)